# Swift DateFormatter - Parse from UTC String

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I'm using a String extension to parse utc string to Date. But the parsed date is wrong. Not sure what i'm missing.

```
extension String {
var parseUTCDateTime:Date? {
    let parser = DateFormatter()
    parser.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"
    if let result = parser.date(from: self) {
       return result
    }
    return nil
}
```

When I do `"3/7/2022 7:40:17 AM".parseUTCDateTime`, the result returned `2022-03-06 19:10:17 UTC`.

Ideally the result should be `2022-03-06 07:10:17 UTC` as the string contains AM in it.

Comment: In what timezone are you?

Comment: try using `hh` instead of `HH`. `HH` is for `24h` method.

Comment: @burnsi I'm in IST timezone

Comment: @udi changing to ```hh``` returns - ```2022-03-07 02:10:17 UTC```

Comment: Set the time zone property of your formatter to UTC if that is what the input time is, by default it is using the current time zone of the device.

Comment: changing to ```hh``` and adding timezone UTC to the converter worked. Thanks

Comment: @Iniamudhan make sure to set your date formatter's calendar to Gregorian or ISO8601 to avoid parsing the year based on the device's calendar. If the user's calendar is set to Buddhist calendar it would parse the year with 500 years offset. You need also to set its locale to "en_US_POSIX" otherwise the date formatter would reflect the user devices locale and settings. More specifically the 24 hour settings which is definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Format strings have [type-safe interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/formatstring/stringinterpolation?language=Swift) now, so you don't need to worry about the `hh` vs `HH` anymore that tripped you up.

```swift
try Date(utc: "3/7/2022 7:40:17 AM")
```

```swift
extension Date {
  init(utc string: ParseStrategy.ParseInput) throws {
    try self.init(
      string,
      strategy: ParseStrategy(
        format: """
          \(month: .defaultDigits)\
          /\(day: .defaultDigits)\
          /\(year: .defaultDigits)

          \(hour: .defaultDigits(clock: .twelveHour, hourCycle: .oneBased))\
          :\(minute: .defaultDigits)\
          :\(second: .defaultDigits)

          \(dayPeriod: .standard(.narrow))
          """,
        timeZone: .init(abbreviation: "UTC")!,
        isLenient: false
      )
    )
  }
}
```